# Changing background of icons in metro Windows 8 interface

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Is it possible to change a non-Metro application's background color like Mozilla Thunderbird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it will change it for all of your non-Metro icons and requires you change your Metro UI color scheme as well.

To do this:

1. Go to Start (or use <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>) and type in "Customize your Start Screen". You'll be able to access it from the Settings search filter.
2. Next, click one of the color schemes at the bottom where the outer color matches what you want your icons to have, and you've successfully changed it!